# PHP Mailer Coding Issue

Tags: php, phpmailer

I am having an issue with getting my PHP mailer code to work correctly.  I can get it to send an email on page load fine, the issue is with the ISSET command to get it to submit the form once the submit button has been pressed.  I have tried putting it in various places but still can't get it to work.  Any help would be appreciated.

```
<?php
require '/phpmailer/PHPMailerAutoload.php';
require_once '/phpmailer/class.phpmailer.php';
include '/phpmailer/class.smtp.php';

if(isset($_POST["Submit"])) 
{

$emailaddress = '****@**********';

$message=
    'Name:  '.$_POST['name'].'<br />
    Email:  '.$_POST['email'].'<br />
    IP: '.$_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'].'<br /><br />
    Message:<br /><br />
    '.nl2br($_POST['message']).'
    ';

$mail             = new PHPMailer();
$mail->IsSMTP(); // telling the class to use SMTP
$mail->Host       = "********"; // SMTP server
$mail->SMTPDebug  = 1;                     // 1 = errors and messages,2 = messages only
$mail->SMTPAuth   = false;                  // enable SMTP authentication
$mail->Port       = 25;                    // set the SMTP port for the GMAIL server
$mail->SMTPSecure = 'false';                            // Enable encryption, 'ssl' also accepted
$mail->CharSet  = 'UTF-8';  // so it interprets foreign characters
$mail->setFrom('***********');
$mail->AddReplyTo('**********');
$mail->Subject    = "Contact form submission from ".$_POST['name']." ";
$mail->MsgHTML($message);
$mail->AddAddress($emailaddress);

if(!$mail->Send())
{
    echo "Message could not be sent. <p>";
    echo "Mailer Error: " . $mail->ErrorInfo;
    exit;
}

    echo "Thank you, your message has been sent!";
}
```

Comment: Your conditional `if(isset($_POST["Submit"]))` is based on a submit button named `Submit`. If your submit button has `name="submit"` instead of `name="Submit"`, then that would explain it. If it isn't named, then **do**. That's the only conclusion I can come up with. Post your HTML form to be 100% sure.

Comment: Thank you!  I for some reason thought buttons only needed the button type and value="submit".  Once I added the name attribute it worked.

Comment: You don't need to `require` anything but the autoloader - that's the whole point of it!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm going to make my comment as an answer, because that is the only conclusion I can come up with and the most likely to be, without seeing the OP's HTML form.

Your conditional statement `if(isset($_POST["Submit"]))` is based on a submit button named `Submit`. If your submit button has `name="submit"` instead of `name="Submit"`, then that would explain it. If it isn't named, then **do**.

I.e.:

```
<input type="submit" name="Submit" value="Send Email">
```

is not the same as

```
<input type="submit" name="submit" value="Send Email">
```

- POST variables are case-sensitive.

Your presently shown code has the proper bracing.

Having used [**error reporting**](http://php.net/manual/en/function.error-reporting.php) and placed the top of your file(s) right after your opening `<?php` tag

```
error_reporting(E_ALL);
ini_set('display_errors', 1);
```

would have signaled an `Undefined index Submit...` warning message.

Comment: I'm not sure but I also think the submit button needs a value attribute to be counted as set by `isset`

Comment: @TomKriek The value is only to show the button's word to echo as. If there is no value, then the word "Submit" automatically appears as its default value.

Comment: I didn't have a name="" value for my button.  I thought I only needed a type and value.  I added a name="submit" and it works.  Thank you!

Comment: @user3630457 You're welcome, glad to have been of help, *cheers* - I take it you will mark it as solved.

Comment: One small thing: Safer than `isset` is to use the somewhat more accurate `array_key_exists`, as that will reliably detect submitted fields even if they lack a value, and also does not rely on isset's error suppression by not triggering them in the first place.

Comment: @Synchro That's a very good point Synchro, thanks for the added information. +1